# Firebase/Android - Regularly losing database connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I followed the docs for Firebase Auth and Database.

Everything works fine after a fresh install:

The user can register or log in, the data is retrieved like it should, written like it should, super fast, super clean. yay.

And then, after a few restarts via android Studio, the database stuff does not work anymore. The amount of restarts varies, I could not find a rule or such. If I uninstall and reinstall the apk (still via Android Studio) it works again.

I'm monitoring the auth state, the user stays logged in, there are also no firebase error at all.

I get a ton of `E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class:` but apparently this is not an error (just mentioning it because I get 20+ consecutive lines of that "error".

Any idea where I should start looking?

### app.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

### Firebase database rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `CompletionListeners` on your setValue() calls, and in the failed state they never fire?  Do you have a [listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) for ".info/connected" that is reporting loss of connection?

Comment: @qbix thank! I'll look into that and come back to you!

Comment: @qbix It happened again and the listener showed that the `.info/connected` bit was set to false. There was no error though.

Comment: The Firebase debug logs are very detailed and would likely provide some explanation for the connection problem.  Enable debug level logging  using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` and examine the logcat output at the time you lose connection.  Post the section of interest if you want help reviewing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may be experiencing a known problem caused with auth token refresh failure [discussed here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=sl#!topic/firebase-talk/CjE9ra_nwrw).  Try enabling debug level logging using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` and compare the output with the samples included in the discussion linked above. In particular, look for "Error fetching token: An internal error has occured. [ Internal error. ]".  If you see that, follow the [instructions provided here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view) to fix your google-services.json file.

Comment: Quick update: I had to switch phones because I broke, one could say destroyed, my oneplus one. So I switched from android 6.0 to 4.3 and I did not have the problem since.

Comment: There it happened again and what you suggested seems to have worked! I thank you very much for your help! I'll keep an eye on it and come back to accept and give you the bounty if this permanently solves the problem :)