# Data stops being retrieved from Firebase database after a few hours

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got an Android application that uses Firebase password and email authentication and the real time database. This all works completely fine when the user has just logged in.

However maybe a few hours later data will stop being shown even if the data changes in the database, it almost seems as though the user is no longer authenticated. But when I connect my device to the adb I can see in the log that the user is logged in with the correct uid and there are no errors being reported. The only strange thing I noticed is that there is no network requests in the network monitor.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening? I'm not sure if it's a database problem or an authentication problem. I can provide any information needed

**EDIT**

Marked answer down below but also take a look at [these instructions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94LePkXiqa6SXVFd3N1NzJHX1E/view) also when adding your SHA1 Keys to firebase, add both production and dev copies

Comment: What version are you on? 9.0.2 fixed a problem with authentication refresh, so make sure you're on that one at least.

Comment: yep I'm on 9.0.2 for every Firebase module

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37749990/4815718) helped another user experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add SHA1 of your debug and production certificates to Firebase console.

It is needed so firebase knows your app has access to refresh access token.

Docs Reference: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/launch-checklist

Comment: I generated a signed debug apk, got the SHA1 and added it to my firebase project, it was already in the google api console. Still not working, do I need to create a production apk too?

Comment: You need to add it to firebase console too.

Comment: Sorry that's what I meant when I said I added it to my firebase project, doesn't seemed to have worked